# SQL Calculation based on value in other column

Tags: mysql

could use some help with an SQL query...I have a table containing a number of columns.  See below sample:

```
Organisation | Resoure1 | Resource2 | Type
A            |        1 |         4 | W
B            |        4 |         5 | L
C            |        4 |         6 | W
D            |        5 |         3 | W
E            |        4 |         2 | L
A            |        4 |         4 | L
C            |        3 |         5 | L
```

I have a query that reads from this table and inputs data in another table:

```
INSERT INTO daily_totals 
(Organisation, Resource1, Resource2, Type) 
SELECT Organisation
     , sum(Resource1)
     , sum(Resource2)
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Type LIKE "W%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  FROM db.mytable 
 GROUP 
    BY organisation;
```

However, I now need a small modification to the above part `SUM(CASE WHEN Type LIKE "W%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` - column TYPE in total needs to be dependent on Resource1 - Odd numbers in Resource1 need to be rounded to nearest Even number and then halved.  Therefore I need to do something like:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Type LIKE "W%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * CEILING(sum(CASE WHEN Resource1 = 1 THEN 2 ELSE Resource1 END) / 2 WHERE Type LIKE "W%")
```

But this results in syntax errors and I cannot figure out a way round it.

Can I get some help with the syntax?

Desired Output in table "Totals":

```
Organisation | Resource1 | Resource2 | Type
A | 5 | 8 | 2
B | 4 | 5 | 0
C | 7 | 11 | 2
D | 5 | 3 | 3
E | 4 | 2 | 0
```

Comment: Provide desired output with explanations.

Comment: You can't have `WHERE` inside the call to `CEILING`. I don't understand what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Did you really intend to put that there, or was it just an editing mistake?

Comment: The names of your columns seem to have changed at the end of the question. `Type` turned into `guestOs`, `Resource1` became `numberOfCpus`.

Comment: I really can't figure out what you're trying to do. You're not rounding anything to the nearest even number, you're just changing `1` to `2`.

Comment: You can round an odd number up to the next even number with `IF(num%2 = 1, num+1, num)`

Comment: You can also use `CEILING` after dividing, but before summing: `SUM(CEILING(num/2))`

Comment: The syntax error is because of `WHERE guestOs LIKE "W%"`. I'll ask again: why is that there?

Comment: Use `IF` or `CASE` if you only want to do this rounding when `guestOs LIKE 'W%'`

Comment: @Barmar more like move that criterion into the 2nd case statement with an `and` condition

Comment: @Barmar you're right I fixed the column names below.

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to do the following:

Sum Resource 2 per Organisation (this works), then Sum Resource 1 for Organisation (this works), then Sum Type for Organisation IF Type is W (this works by using `SUM(CASE WHEN Type LIKE "W%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Now I need another summation which reads as follows: If Type is W, then assume its a "1".  Now, multiply Resource1 by "1" and divide final value by 2.  However, if Resource1 is an ODD number it must be made into an EVEN number first.

Comment: @Akina added desired output table

Comment: *Odd numbers in Resource1 need to be rounded to nearest Even number* Ambiguous. For odd 5 both even 4 and 6 have the same distance (1) - which is nearest? and why? And show the calculations for `Type` values for each final row. Especially for Organisation = 'D'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Type LIKE 'W%' 
    THEN IF(Resource1 % 2 = 1, Resource1 + 1, Resource1) 
    ELSE 0
    END) / 2
```

Comment: Works - Originally threw a Syntax error and revised to:

`SUM(CASE WHEN Type LIKE 'W%' 
    THEN IF(Resource1 % 2 = 1, Resource1 + 1, Resource1) 
    ELSE 0
    END) / 2`

Thanks!!